# JavaScript, Cannot read property of undefined, but it's defined

Tags: javascript

I don't know why I'm getting this `undefined` on a var that I can see on console.log. There's no asynch calls.

```
if (gLayer) {
    /* This code works ok, but I don't want to use this way, instead, I want to use the next block code:

    var longZoom = gLayer.graphics[0].geometry.rings[0][0][0];
    var latZoom = gLayer.graphics[0].geometry.rings[0][0][1];
    zoomToLocationLatLon(latZoom, longZoom, false, 12);

    */


    console.log('gLayer', gLayer); // I can see in the console the var gLayer
    console.log('gLayer.graphics', gLayer.graphics); // I can see in the console the var gLayer.graphics, its an array of ~1200 rows
    if(gLayer.graphics && gLayer.graphics.length > 0) {
        var ge = GraphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(gLayer.graphics);  <-- HERE I HAVE AN ERROR.
        map.setExtent(ge, true);
    }
    gLayer.show();
}
```

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'graphicsExtent' of undefined` Why is saying that is not defined? Actually, with step by step on the JS debugger of Chrome, I can see that is defined ok, as an Array:

[image]

Then in the next step I got:

[image]

Comment: `GraphicUtils` is not defined.

Comment: `GraphicsUtils` is undefined, not `gLayer`.

Comment: Is `GraphicsUtils.graphicsExtent()` defined?

Comment: Maybe try `console.log(GraphicsUtils)` to prove to yourself that it's defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is: `Cannot read property 'graphicsExtent' of undefined`.

The problem is that `GraphicUtils` is `undefined` not `gLayer` or `gLayer.graphics`

Comment: How are these answers not useful? What more is the poster looking for?

Comment: Had to leave the pc, now I'm here, keep calm. Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

the GraphicsUtils is undefined. Your code is not clear about when you defined it or load it. But you can check if the value is available or not:

```
if(gLayer.graphics && gLayer.graphics.length > 0 && GraphicsUtils) {
    var ge = GraphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(gLayer.graphics);
    map.setExtent(ge, true);
} else {
  console.warn('GraphicsUtils is not defined');
}
```

Comment: OP's problem is that GraphUtils is not defined.

Comment: Ah, true. Where are you defining GraphicsUtils?

Comment: @RicardoFerreira in the same part where I define `zoomToLocationLatLon` and that one is working. I think I have a problem with overwriting the function, it has the same name than a js api that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Read the error:  `GraphicsUtils` is undefined not what you have logged.